# No option to enable Apple Pay on Watch

Tags: apple-watch, apple-pay

I have Apple Pay enabled on my iPhone (6S) and it used to be available on Apple Watch (original edition) too. I wiped and restored my watch, and now there is no Apply Pay available. [The instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204506) say to use the Watch app and select "Wallet & Apple Pay". For me the option is just called "Wallet" and the only option is to mirror the iPhone. Searching for "pay" doesn't help. I can make payments successfully with the phone. Both devices have latest OS releases (3.1.3 and 10.2.1 at the time of writing). Where has the option gone and how can I rectify this?

Comment: try : unparing the watch (make a backup) and re pair it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the region your iPhone and your Apple Watch are set to. This is a quote from [Apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205630), emphasis mine:

> 1. Make sure that you're in a supported region.
>
>    - For your iPhone or iPad, go to Settings > General > Language & Region, then scroll to Region.
>    - For your **Apple Watch**, open the Watch app on your iPhone, go to the My **Watch tab, tap General > Language & Region**, and check the region
>        format.

I had a similar issue in the past and was able to solve it after setting the correct region and restarting both devices.

Let me know if it worked for you as well.

Comment: Wow, yes, unintuitive but indeed watch region was set to current location instead of region preference/card country. No restarts required: change region and go back to Wallet menu, start process of adding card to watch.