# Wallet and Pay and Reminders disappeared after re-pairing Apple Watch with watchOS 6.1

Tags: watchos, apple-pay, apple-watch.app

I have *Apple Watch 2 Series* and *iPhone 6S*. Recently I've got an update to *IOS 13* on iPhone and *watchOS 6.1* on Apple Watch. After upgrade **Reminders** stopped syncing. I tried to resolve the problem by unpairing the watch and pairing it again using backup to restore. Now strange thing has happened: **Wallet & Pay** option *disappeared* from Apps list in *Watch* application. So I cannot add any cards to my watch anymore. **Reminders** app also disappeared from the watch. I tried to uninstall the iPhone app Reminders and install it again, but it didn't have any effect on the watch. To resolve problem with the **Wallet & Pay** on Apple Watch I tried to change regions on both iPhone and Apple Watch - no luck. iPhone have Apple Pay app and is able to manage cards.

Any ideas what I can try else to recover function of **Wallet & Pay** app and **Reminders**?

This is different from [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276602/no-option-to-enable-apple-pay-on-watch) question, where OP could solve his problem by setting correct region for his watch. I already have region set to the country, which participates in Apple Pay programm.

**Update 1:**

The Wallet & Pay menu has reappeared in Watch App after I *unpaired* and *paired* the watch as a **new device** (not using backup to restore). Reminders and a bunch of other very useful apps is still not available on the watch. The problem becomes more clear: **iPhone cannot install any app on the watch**. In the watch management app on the iPhone it is visible that iPhone tries to start the installation - rotating circle, but nothing happens for many hours.

**Update 2:**

Resetting network settings on iPhone and joining again to Wifi seems to restore synchronization between iPhone and the watch: apps now can be installed, calendar get updates. **Reminder** app is still not available on the watch. Tried re-installing app on the phone: no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally, I found the solution, which I'd like to share here:

Reminder app has never appeared in the list of installed apps, neither in the Watch app on the iPhone, nor on the Apple Watch itself (in contrast to Calendar, and in contrast to the situation before the upgrade to watchOS 6).

BUT: while configuring the **watch facet**, I saw **Reminder** as a possible **complication** to choose. I tried it to select and it opened the new version of Reminders app. It was a bit laggy, but it worked: all reminders were synchronized with the iPhone.